# Ember, Handlebars and shared conditions

Tags: if-statement, ember.js, handlebars.js, conditional-statements

I have an application with several routes, there are elements in each template which should be displayed (or hidden) - using the same condition, therefore I created a one `Central` controller where I'm declaring the condition and then overriding the methods in each controller like (pseudo code):

```
App.CentralController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    canEdit: function(){ return someCalculatedBool; }.property('view'),
    canSomethingElse: function(){ return someOtherBool; }.property('view')
});

App.DetailsController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    needs: ['central'], 
    canEdit: function(){ return this.get('controllers.central').canEdit() }.property('view'),
    canSomethingElse: function(){ return this.get('controllers.central').canSomethingElse(); }.property('view')
})
```

So in Handlebars template for Details I can use it like:

```
{{#if canEdit}}
    [Edit Button]
{{/if}}
```

Anyway conditions count grows and I need to overrride each condition method in each controller, which isn't optimal.

**Question:** How can I use these conditions in the view pointing directly to the `Central` controller?

Vesions:

- Ember: `1.1.2`
- Handlebars: `1.0.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add an alias to the controller and use a dot-path in the view:

```
App.DetailsController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs: ['central'],
  central: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.central')
});


{{#if central.canEdit}}
  [Edit Button]
{{/if}}
```

Comment: it's helpful to remember you can use dotpaths in `get` & `set` as well -- this is part of Ember's NextStep legacy. Saves a lot of typing -- especially when you want a null when any part of the chain is null, which `get`/`set` will do for you. Just watch out for Demeter ;)

Comment: That's the knowledge I was missing ;) thx, btw, has this approach some significant performance impact?

Comment: I haven't benchmarked it. I doubt it is significant as long as you aren't creating properties that depend on each other in a way that takes many passes to resolve, something you have to watch for when using `observes`. The only overhead in using dotpaths in `get`/`set` over constructing the chain manually is the initial string split.